# Matlab Increase thickness of lines of 3d bars

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D bar chart. Let me clarify, I do not want to edit the width of the bar graph as I have already done that. However, there are black lines that outline each bar. Is there a way to make these thicker?

Everything I have search pays reference to the width of the bars themselves, not the black lines enclosing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I found the answer to my own question the minute after I ask it.

Simply:

```
set(j,'LineWidth',1.5)
```

EDIT: As Luis mentioned, j is the handle such that j = bar3(...)

Sorry should have included that.

Comment: ... where `j` is a handle to the graphic object, i.e. `j = bar3(...)`. You should clarify that in your answer. And [`j` is not a good choice for a variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)